# VBA MsgBox IF statements?

Tags: excel, vba, if-statement

I'm trying to set up an IF statement for a vba MsgBox with YES/NO responses. Is it possible? This is what I have:

```
Sub EmailAttachments()

Dim Msg001 As String
Dim Msg002 As String

Msg001 = "Continue creating your email"
Msg002 = "Save your attachments prior to creating an email"

MsgBox "Have you saved your attachments", vbYesNo, "ATTENTION!"

If vb = Yes Then
MsgBox Msg001, vbOKOnly, "CONTINUE"
Else
MsgBox Msg002, vbOKOnly, "EMAIL NOT CREATED"
End if

End Sub
```

Comment: What is not working as intended? Please use the correct return values of a MsgBox (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/msgbox-function)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please, use the  next way:

```
Sub EmailAttachments()
 Dim Msg001 As String, Msg002 As String, answer As VbMsgBoxResult

 Msg001 = "Continue creating your email"
 Msg002 = "Save your attachments prior to creating an email"

 answer = MsgBox("Have you saved your attachments?", vbYesNo, "ATTENTION!")

 If answer = vbYes Then
        MsgBox Msg001, vbOKOnly, "CONTINUE"
 Else
        MsgBox Msg002, vbOKOnly, "EMAIL NOT CREATED"
 End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Your messages can be constants instead of variables, because their strings will not change: Instead of `Dim` use directly `Const Msg001 As String = "Continue creating your email"`

Comment: @Pᴇʜ Yes, they can. I only adapted his code to make it working. I would not use the two variables at all. Since they are not changed and used more than once, the compact/normal solution will be to write the strings like `MsgBox` parameters. Like: `MsgBox "Continue creating your email", vbOKOnly, "CONTINUE"`...

Comment: Sorry, that comment was actually meant for the OP. Should have made that more clear.