# Why is this still adding +1 when I don't want it to?

Tags: vb.net

I'm coding a basketball scoreboard and I have a final score and a free throw score shown in the main form. This is a controller that will relay the information to the main form. It has a score button and a free throw button (both have a +1 and -1 button). To make lives easier, I've decided to add a yes/no question to the main +1 score of it, so the user doesn't have to press +1 for free throws manually after clicking +1 on the main score, and it should add a score to the free thrown and not add one when inputted "No". But, the thing is, this still adds +1 even if I press no. Why? What should I do?

```
Private Sub btnT1Sp1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnT1Sp1.Click 'Score +1
        Form1.lblT1pnts.Text = Val(Form1.lblT1pnts.Text) + 1
        MsgBox("Was this a freethrow?", vbQuestion + vbYesNo, "Controller")
        If vbYes Then
            Form1.lblFreeThrowsT1.Text = Val(Form1.lblFreeThrowsT1.Text) + 1
        Else
            Me.Close()
            Me.Dispose()
        End If
    End Sub
```

I've tried:

```
Private Sub btnT1Sp1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnT1Sp1.Click 'Score +1
        Form1.lblT1pnts.Text = Val(Form1.lblT1pnts.Text) + 1
        MsgBox("Was this a freethrow?", vbQuestion + vbYesNo, "Controller")
        If vbYes Then
            Form1.lblFreeThrowsT1.Text = Val(Form1.lblFreeThrowsT1.Text) + 1
        Else
            Form1.lblFreeThrowsT1.Text = Val(Form1.lblFreeThrowsT1.Text) - 1
            Me.Close()
            Me.Dispose()
        End If
    End Sub
```

```
Private Sub btnT1Sp1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnT1Sp1.Click 'Score +1
        Form1.lblT1pnts.Text = Val(Form1.lblT1pnts.Text) + 1
        MsgBox("Was this a freethrow?", vbQuestion + vbYesNo, "Controller")
        If vbYes Then
            Form1.lblFreeThrowsT1.Text = Val(Form1.lblFreeThrowsT1.Text) + 1
        Elseif vbNo Then
            Me.Close()
            Me.Dispose()
        End If
    End Sub
```

```
Private Sub btnT1Sp1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnT1Sp1.Click 'Score +1
        Form1.lblT1pnts.Text = Val(Form1.lblT1pnts.Text) + 1
        MsgBox("Was this a freethrow?", vbQuestion + vbYesNo, "Controller")
        If vbYes Then
            Form1.lblFreeThrowsT1.Text = Val(Form1.lblFreeThrowsT1.Text) + 1
        Elseif vbNo Then
            Form1.lblFreeThrowsT1.Text = Val(Form1.lblFreeThrowsT1.Text) - 1
        End If
    End Sub
```

```
Private Sub btnT1Sp1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnT1Sp1.Click 'Score +1
        Form1.lblT1pnts.Text = Val(Form1.lblT1pnts.Text) + 1
        MsgBox("Was this a freethrow?", vbQuestion + vbYesNo, "Controller")
        If vbYes Then
            Form1.lblFreeThrowsT1.Text = Val(Form1.lblFreeThrowsT1.Text) + 1
        Elseif vbNo Then
            Return
        End If
    End Sub
```

Comment: You need to use the value which `MsgBox` returns: there are some examples at [MessageBox.Show Examples](https://www.dotnetperls.com/messagebox-show-vbnet). (MessageBox.Show is the modern version of MsgBox.)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [VBA MsgBox IF statements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74051719/vba-msgbox-if-statements)

Comment: @FunThomas surprisingly, yes. I just declared a new variable and made that the result of vbYes and that worked. How does that work?

Comment: `vbYes` is just a constant (I think 6, but that doesn't matter), and `if vbYes` is the same as `if 6`. You need to check the result of the messageBox against that value. Either by assigning it to a variable, or by checking it direclty: `If MsgBox("Was this a freethrow?", vbQuestion + vbYesNo, "Controller") = vbYes Then`

Answer (score 0):

You must use the result of the message box:

```vb
Dim result = MsgBox("Was this a freethrow?", vbQuestion + vbYesNo, "Controller")
If result = MsgBoxResult.Yes Then

Else 'No

End If
```

Since you specified `vbYesNo` when calling `MsgBox`, there is no point in testing for `No` with an `Elseif`. If the result is not `Yes`, it can only be `No`. The `Else` part is only executed if the `Then` part is not executed.